# Release memory when form close

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory-management, windows

I searched a lot about releasing memory when form close,
but I didn't find any solution for releasing memory used by form.
Most of the answer in stackoverflow or other forums is form.Dispose() or GC.Collect() will not help for releasing memory.

But I found an article [Release memory in Windows Form application using C#](http://codesmithdotnet.blogspot.com/2008/02/release-memory-in-windows-form.html) (http://codesmithdotnet.blogspot.com/2008/02/release-memory-in-windows-form.html)

Fortunately the code from the article working fine :)

```
public class MemoryManagement
{
    [DllImportAttribute("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetProcessWorkingSetSize", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr process, int minimumWorkingSetSize, int maximumWorkingSetSize);

    public static void FlushMemory()
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
        {
            SetProcessWorkingSetSize(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, -1, -1);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, Is anyone familiar about the method "SetProcessWorkingSetSize"? / How it works? / Is this way is good for releasing memory? Is this will cause any issue or this will make application slow?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The recommendation is not doing it, Garbage Collector will do it for you.

Comment: This is .NET  - leave memory management to the Garbage Collector. There are best practices like calling Dispose() on IDisposable's but not sure what you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @poke, the answer for your question is my question. After the form is closed the memory allocated for that form is not released. So I try to release the memory using that code.

Comment: That doesn’t answer *why* you want to manually release the memory. Why do you care about it in the first place?

Comment: What makes you think the memory is not being released?

Comment: @YohanesNurcahyo and Kevin, The Garbage Collector / Dispose() is not releasing the memory after form closed.

Comment: @poke and Kevin, When I looking my application process in Task Manager the memory is keep growing so sometime application throws Out Of Memory exception.

Comment: "The Garbage Collector / Dispose() is not releasing the memory after form closed." Can you prove this statement using the Memory Profiler?

Comment: @PalaniKumar Then that’s a sign that you don’t dispose your objects properly. Calling the garbage collector manually won’t change that.

Comment: @kirmir,  I didn't used Memory Profiler before. I think you mention this http://memprofiler.com/. Let me check with this.

Comment: Use any memory profiler (I used ANTS for example) and check what causes your forms to not release.

Comment: If there was a memory leak problem with WinForms people would have noticed 10 years ago. Your code isn't releasing memory when it should, or it's creating a lot of temporary objects (eg temporary strings) without releasing them. Forcing a garbage collection may *hide* the problem but it's still there

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292229/pros-and-cons-of-using-setprocessworkingsetsize)

`SetProcessWorkingSetSize()` controls the amount of RAM that your process uses. `SetProcessWorkingSetSize` is typically used to increase the amount of RAM allocated for a process.

1:- How it works?

> Ans:- Suppose I have many Forms or dialog boxes in my application, I
>   want to call `SetProcessWorkingSetSize()` after I close each form or
>   dialog box, so that the OS frees the resources.

2:- Is this way is good for releasing memory?

> Ans:-I think No. Windows is already quite good at dynamically
>   controlling this, swapping memory pages out on demand when another
>   process needs RAM. By doing this manually, you slow down your program
>   a lot, causing a lot of page faults when Windows is forced to swap the
>   memory pages back in.

3:-Is this will cause any issue or this will make application slow?

> Ans:-Yes mentioned in answer 2.

Answer (score 1):

You should release only the external unmanaged resources (close opened connections, file handlers, etc.) and do that using the `Dispose` method implemented by that resources.

No need to try to force GC to release managed objects related to Forms. In 99% cases don't call GC at all.

No need to use external Windows API methods, it's not a *.NET way*. Read how memory management works on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691138(v=vs.71).aspx).

You should find *why* your managed objects are not disposed.

As for WinForms: most problems might be caused by left event handlers. Check more details on already answered question [Memory Leaks in Winforms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891567/memory-leaks-in-winforms-application). Use any Memory Profiler (e.g. ANTS) in order to find references which keeps your Forms objects from releasing.